# MissingSourceFile (no such file to load -- RMagick) linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rmagick

The error message seems general, but am unable to fix the issue even after google it.

Server details:

- Red Hat Linux Dedicated Server,
- ruby  v = 1.8.7
- gem v = 2.0.17
- rails v = 2.1.2
- Image Magick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x86_64
- RMagick v = 2.15.4

Installed rails using RVM. All other gems(mysql, payments, rails and etc) are working fine but RMagick is not working at all, whatever I try I get an error like `MissingSourceFile (no such file to load -- RMagick)`

All gems are installed in `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/` apart from RMagick, which is installed in the following locations:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/doc/rmagick-2.15.4/ri/RMagick     ,  
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rmagick-2.15.4/ext/RMagick
```

Is there a version problem?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing RMagick?

Comment: yea, i tried more than once, but same issue everytime

Comment: any one have any idea, am unable to do further step without this RMagick for my project,